# Accessor: cannot find symbol error.

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java, so bear with me.

I'm using x and y variables inside a coordinate array.

Mutator:

```
  public void setCoordinate (double _x, double _y) {
     x = _x;
     y = _y;
     double [] coordinate = new double [2];
     coordinate[0] = x;
     coordinate[1] = y;
  }
```

The part I'm having trouble with is the accessor:

```
   public double[] getCoordinate() {
     return "(" + coordinate[0] + ", " + coordinate[1] + ")";
   }
```

I'm getting a "**symbol: variable coordinate, location: class Address, error: cannot find symbol**" error. Any idea as to why I'm getting this error? I wrote the other accessors the same way and I'm not having any trouble.

---

Also... how would I call each variable (x and y) separately in another method? a1.getCoordinate() returns both values (x, y), but I want to use x and y in an equation later on an I'm not 100% sure of how to do this.

Comment: You're returning a string instead of a double array... not to mention the scope mess you have there...

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is due to the coordinate variable being declared inside of the `setCoordinate(...)` method, and thus it is visible only in this method and invisible everywhere else. In other words, its *scope* is limited to the method.

One solution to this problem is to make coordinate a class field, but if you do this, then you will want to get rid of the x and y class fields since they will be unnecessary duplicate variables and can lead to confusion if x and y somehow get out of sync with coordinate. i.e.,

```
private double[] coordinate;

public void setCoordinate(double x, double y) {
   coordinate = new double[]{x, y};  // coordinate is a class field
}

public double[] getCoordinate() { 
  coordinate;
}
```

Alternatively you can keep x and y and simply create a double array object on the fly inside of the `getCoordinate()` method with your x and y variables as the need arises. i.e.,

```
private double x;
private double y;

public void setCoordinate(double x, double y) {
   this.x = x;  // x is a class field
   this.y = y;  // y is a class field
}

public double[] getCoordinate() { 
  return new double[] {x, y};
}
```

---

Your second problem is that the `getCoordinate()` methods declares that it will return a double array:

```
public double[] getCoordinate() {
```

but you're trying to return a **String**:

```
  return "(" + coordinate[0] + ", " + coordinate[1] + ")";
```

You don't want to do this since it "breaks the method's contract", since you're not returning the type you've promised to return. Instead return the type that the method has been declared to return (or a child type of the declared type since return types allow for "covariance" -- but this is not applicable in your situation).

Answer (score 1):

```
double [] coordinate = new double [2];
```

should be declared outside the mutator as its scope is only for that mutator.

You should have something as follows:

```
class SomeClass{
    double [] coordinate = new double [2];
    int x, y;
    public double[] getCoordinate;
    //methods
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining coordinate in the scope of the setCoordinate function. You'll need to define coordinate at the class level in order to access it in both methods.